# How do I prevent an iframe from capturing the background color of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, embed

I maybe wrong in my approach here but I created an HTML5/Javascript container that uses javascript to glow the text and to use a countdown.  I was however able to achieve the iframe result i was seeking after great difficulty but the only thing is that the background color of the page on which i have the widget if you will is in red color so now wherever the iframe is being embedded it moves around the widget and shows the background color.

I thought of changing the color to white but that still has problems with the positioning so I am wondering if there are something that i need to fix on the page OR how do i make sure only the part i want from the page is embedded?

Comment: If you include some of the actual code your problem lies in, people may be more readily able to help

Comment: Hey.  Give me a few mins to post the code.  Thanks!

Comment: Hey! Here is the jsfiddle link the code:  http://jsfiddle.net/f29rc/

The black box is what i need to be wrapped in an iframe and i need it to be done perfectly.  So not sure why it won't work with that i have.  This is how I am calling it:  <iframe src="http://www.domain.me/psy/demo.html" class="iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="200px" height="400px"></iframe>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without more information this is a long shot but try to put a `background-color:transparent`; on the offending widget or simply do not use a background color on it so that is does not overflow your desired space.

Comment: Hey! Here is the jsfiddle link the code: jsfiddle.net/f29rc The black box is what i need to be wrapped in an iframe and i need it to be done perfectly. So not sure why it won't work with that i have. This is how I am calling it: <iframe src="domain.me/psy/demo.html"; class="iframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" width="200px" height="400px"></iframe>

Comment: btw i tried using a white color but the problem is then it still renders the iframe that way but the gap still shows.